# Как добавить Инерцию камере при свайпе Unity

Tags: unity3d, физика

```
Камера вращается относительно таргета замечательно, но вот хочу добавить инерцию после свайпа, допустим отжал палец и камера немного сдвигалась в этом направлении. Есть варианты с помощью Rigidbody. Но вот с камерой возникли проблемы

public Transform target;
    public Vector3 offset;
    public float sensitivity = 3; // чувствительность мышки
    public float limit = 80; // ограничение вращения по Y
    public float zoom = 0.25f; // чувствительность при увеличении, колесиком мышки
    public float zoomMax = 10; // макс. увеличение
    public float zoomMin = 3; // мин. увеличение
    private float X, Y;

    public float DistanceInerCial;

    void Start()
    {
        limit = Mathf.Abs(limit);
        if (limit > 90) limit = 90;
        offset = new Vector3(offset.x, offset.y, -Mathf.Abs(zoomMax) / 2);
        Camera.main.transform.position = Camera.main.transform.localRotation * offset + target.position;
    }
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0) offset.z += zoom;
        else if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0) offset.z -= zoom;
        offset.z = Mathf.Clamp(offset.z, -Mathf.Abs(zoomMax), -Mathf.Abs(zoomMin));

        X = Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles.y + eventData.delta.x * sensitivity;
        Y += eventData.delta.y * sensitivity;
        Y = Mathf.Clamp(Y, -limit, limit);
        Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-Y, X, 0);
        Camera.main.transform.position = Camera.main.transform.localRotation * offset + target.position;

        DistanceInerCial = Camera.main.transform.localEulerAngles.y + 10;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ - использовать внешние библиотеки вроде LeanTween или аналогов.

Там можно делать и смену позиции и поворота и добавлять к ним Ease разных вариаций:

```
LeanTween.rotateX(gameObject, 270.0f, 1.5f)
         .setEase(LeanTweenType.easeInBack);
```

Вот по этой табличке можно выбрать наиболее подходящую функцию лично тебе:
https://easings.net

просто наведи на любую функцию мышку.

Comment: А вот с помощью Rigidbody, какие есть варианты?.

Comment: А при чем здесь вообще Rigidbody ? Это компонент для работы с физикой

Comment: https://youtu.be/2LFCESORY6s, посмотри не могу понять как лучше сделать инерцию что бы после свайпа в ту сторону двигалась камера

Comment: Это отдельный вопрос от этого и это нужно смотреть только с кодом. Я ж не знаю как именно ты это все реализовал и что именно ты сделал не так. Этот вопрос был в том как делаются Ease при движениях - я подсказал.